# github download entire directory in raw format

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I just wonder what would be the best way to download an entire GitHub directory/folder in raw format using a command line instead of using the GUI.

I need to download all the existing files and there is a long list.
What would you recommend?

Comment: I suggest you to check these posts: [How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository) and [Download a single folder or directory from a GitHub repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- [curl the archive of the GitHub repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21413875/6309) (HEAD content as a zip or tar file)
  Example:

  ```
  curl -LkSs https://api.github.com/repos/ziyaddin/xampp/tarball -o master.tar.gz
  ```
- [extract from that tar file a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24235313/6309)
  Example:

  ```
  tar -xzf backup.tar.gz --strip-components=3 -C a/b/m
  ```

You can extract any file or folder from that archive.

Comment: Does this work publicly and what are the limits?

Comment: @Pacerier I suspect it works only on public repository, and I do not know if there is a limit (in term of archive size)